# How to integrate littlefoot.js with Vue.js (Nuxt.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

littlefoot js is a "fancy" footnote replacement plugin. In the docs, its author says this is how it can be used with Gatsby:

```
import littlefoot from 'littlefoot'
import 'littlefoot/dist/littlefoot.css'

export function onRouteUpdate() {
  littlefoot() // Pass any littlefoot settings here.
}
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with a Nuxt.js app, but without success. As far as I know, this is one possible way to do it in a single component:

```js
<script>
import littlefoot from 'littlefoot'

// ...

export default {
  // ...
  mounted() {
    littlefoot()
  }
}

</script>
```

But that isn't working, the web page simply refuses to load (infinite load) without any error message.

Answer (score 0):

I always do either of the following:

**1:** Import [module](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-modules) in nuxt.config.js

In cmd/terminal

```
npm install --save littlefoot
```

in case you forgot

```
// nuxt.config.js
.
.
modules: [
  'littlefoot'
],
.
.
```

**2**: Create a [plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/) in the /plugins/ directory

Create a file `~/plugins/littlefoot.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import littlefoot from 'littlefoot'
```

Vue.use(littlefoot)

Comment: @isebam - none of them above work. Even when including the plugin appraoch in `nuxt.config.js` `plugins`, and trying `mode: "client"`.

Comment: odd, try restarting npm run dev?

Comment: did that as well.